# Text and GMaps Embed in a container row together in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As a new bootstrap user, I'm trying to get and text and an image to go together side by side in a container.

Like this:

[image]

Blue = Device screen,
Black = visible container

When I try to do this though I find something is causing the maps embed to shift downward.

[image]

There doesn't appear to be any margins or padding in the way ether. I also don't know why the text is blue when I've clearly set it in the CSS to be black.

My HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/locations.css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Locations | Location 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="../index.html">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40" alt="../index.html">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-large nav-text-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Locations</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-mid" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="locations/location1/index.html">Location 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="#">Location 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="#">Location 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="#">Location 4</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-large nav-text-bold" href="#">Media</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-large nav-text-bold" href="donate/index.html">Donate</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-large">
        <a class="nav-link nav-text-bold" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Location 1</h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="text-info">
          <p>1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500</p>
          <br>
          <p>Open Weekdays sometime to sometime</p>
          <br>
          <p>Tel:
          <a href="tel:555-555-5555"><b>555-555-5555</b></a></p>

          <div class="maps-embed">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3105.1501993708266!2d-77.03871848469284!3d38.89768045453255!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89b7b7bcdecbb1df%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sThe%20White%20House!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1574888816470!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
          </div>   
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
<br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

My CSS: (locations.css)

```
.container{
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.text-info{
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

.maps-embed{
  text-align: right;
}

.headerText{
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.text-mid{
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text-mid:hover::after{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text-large{
  font-size: 140%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text-large:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-text-bold{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

EDIT: Someone has provide a half working version that is using Bootstraps Grid system, could someone explain further how the Grid system could be implemented here?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container{
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.text-info{
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

.maps-embed{
  text-align: right;
}

.headerText{
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.text-mid{
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text-mid:hover::after{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text-large{
  font-size: 140%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text-large:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav-text-bold{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/locations.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Locations | Location 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="../index.html">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40" alt="../index.html">
        </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-large nav-text-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Locations</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu text-mid" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="locations/location1/index.html">Location 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="#">Location 2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="#">Location 3</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item nav-text-bold" href="#">Location 4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-large nav-text-bold" href="#">Media</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-large nav-text-bold" href="donate/index.html">Donate</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-large">
                <a class="nav-link nav-text-bold" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="container" id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>Location 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-info">
                <p>1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500</p>
                <br>
                <p>Open Weekdays sometime to sometime</p>
                <br>
                <p>Tel:
                    <a href="tel:555-555-5555"><b>555-555-5555</b></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 maps-embed">
                <iframe
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3105.1501993708266!2d-77.03871848469284!3d38.89768045453255!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89b7b7bcdecbb1df%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sThe%20White%20House!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1574888816470!5m2!1sen!2sus"
                    width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you removed the jumbotron and didn't fix my text coloring issue, I do thank you for cleaning up my code, and I now have reason to believe me problem can be solved with some kind of use of the Bootstrap's grid system, but you fix relys on removing my jumbotron.